# Spark : how can evenly distribute my records in all partition

Tags: apache-spark

I have a RDD with 30 record (key/value pair  :  key is Time Stamp and Value is JPEG Byte Array)
and I am running 30 executors. I want to repartition this RDD in to 30 partitions so every partition gets one record and is assigned to one executor.

When I used `rdd.repartition(30)` it repartitions my rdd in 30 partitions but some partitions get 2 records, some get 1 record and some not getting any records.

Is there any way in Spark I can evenly distribute my records to all partitions.

Comment: RDD already have 4 partition

Comment: When you call `repartition` Spark will indeed repartition your data, but all partitions do not necessarily hold the exact same number of records. The real question here is, why is that important?

Comment: hi i want to perform operation on all 30 records in 1 second using spark streaming . and right now my algo take around 400 ms to perform operation on 1 record . so i want to distribute my records evenly so every executor perform operation only on one record so my 1 second batch will be completed without delay .

Answer (score 3):

**Salting**  technique can be used which involves adding a new "fake" key and using alongside the current key for better distribution of data.

([here is link for salting](https://www.talend.com/blog/2018/03/05/intro-apache-spark-partitioning-need-know/))

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of repartitioning an rdd into `npartitions` partitions, so that the items are evenly distributed across the partitions. The number of items in each partition will be different by at most 1.

```py
evenly_repartitioned = (
    rdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map(lambda p: (p[1], p[0]))
    .partitionBy(N, lambda p: p)
    .values()
)
```

It does:

- Make a tuple of `(item, index)` where the index is over the entire RDD
- Swap the key and the value, so now the RDD contains `(index, item)`
- Repartition to `N` partitions using an identity `partitionFunc`, moving item to partition `index % N`
- Take only the values, dropping the index in the tuple.

Note that this is slower than the default hash-based repartitioning, because it requires another Spark stage during `zipWithIndex()` to count the size of each partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a new partitioning by using the `partitionBy` command and providing a number of partitions. By default the partitioner is a hash-based but you can switch to a range-based for a better distribution. If you really want to force a repartitioning you can use a random number generator as the partition function (in PySpark).

```
my_rdd.partitionBy(pCount, partitionFunc = lambda x: np.random.randint(pCount))
```

This will, however, frequently cause inefficient shuffles (lots of data transferred between nodes), but if your process is compute limited then it can make sense.