# Spark - Equal partitioning of RDD on nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, partitioning

I have an architecture with 4 nodes and a RDD with 4000 rows, and I need to repartition this RDD equally on nodes. The result shoud be:

```
node 1 -> 1000 rows
node 2 -> 1000 rows
node 3 -> 1000 rows
node 4 -> 1000 rows.
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768967/spark-how-can-evenly-distribute-my-records-in-all-partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement the solution already proposed by @sramalingam24 using pyspark as you are already using.

```
from collections import Counter

data = [(i,j) for i,j in zip([i/1000 for i in range(0, 4000, 1)], range(500, 4500, 1))]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ['key', 'values'])
df = df.repartition('key')
```

checking results:

```
Counter(df.select(spark_partition_id()).collect())
Out[*]: Counter({Row(SPARK_PARTITION_ID()=5): 1000, Row(SPARK_PARTITION_ID()=128): 1000, Row(SPARK_PARTITION_ID()=107): 1000, Row(SPARK_PARTITION_ID()=69): 1000})
```

Comment: Thank you @sramalingam24 and @Chiheb.K!! I had no idea about this solution! Thank you very much both.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a textFile to build the rdd you can use:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://.../input.txt", 4)
```

Or you can use :

```
scala> rdd = rdd.repartition(4)
```

rdd.repartition(n) does a shuffle to split data to match n partitions.

Comment: It won't work. `repartiton()`cannot guarantee a uniform distributions across partitions. You will get 4 partitions for certain, but they won't have an even distribution of load.

Comment: I am agree with @cph_sto. I have tried with repartition(n), but it doesn't split equally on nodes.

Comment: @Giulia Why do you even want to strictly have equal distribution of load? IMHO there is no need of it. Had there been added advantages to it, SPARK would have implemented it that way.

Comment: @cph_sto To explain the reason, you should see my dataset, but I am trying to explain you in a simple way. The first 1000 rows of my dataset are informations exclusive for worker0, the second 1000 rows are exclusive for worker1 and so on. If some rows of the first 1000 rows goes on worker1 insted of worker0, there will be a redundance in worker1. So I need to set the number of rows in each partition.

Comment: Take the rdd and zip with index, convert to data frame and do an integer division by 1000 on the index column and repartition by that column. This is of course assuming you don't already have a column that divides the data as you need

Comment: Well, 4000 is in itself a very small number. Let's say you have 100,000 rows and have 4 partitions, then you would have a distribution "resembling" a uniform one.

Comment: See the distribution resembles uniform. This RDD had 100000 elements - `import random
 rdd = sc.parallelize([random.random() for i in range(100000)])
 rdd.collect()
 rdd=rdd.repartition(4)
 print("Number of partitions: {}".format(rdd.getNumPartitions()))
 partitioning_distribution=rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
 print("Number of rows on each partition: "+str(partitioning_distribution))


 Number of partitions: 4
 Number of rows on each partition: [24990, 24990, 24854, 25166]`

Comment: @cph_sto..why even distribution of load among partition won't be beneficial?